Is there a way to turn-off auto-fill and save cache from Telegram.WebView
I want to know a way to delete/not save cache in Telegram WebView (Telegram Mini Apps), turn off auto-fill.
We are using proxy through nginx server. We tried to turn-off cache with no-cache storing header in the nginx conf, but I guess it's not related to Microsoft Web View so as expected it doesn't help at the end.
Example:

